# why does the compilation of identical files in different directories yield different results?

Tags: compilation, g++

I noticed that the object file generated from a source file by g++ in one directory is different from the one generated from an identical source file in another directory:

```
tools_io $ diff -s MoveStats.h ../kernel/MoveStats.h
Files MoveStats.h and ../kernel/MoveStats.h are identical
tools_io $ diff -s MoveStats.cpp ../kernel/MoveStats.cpp
Files MoveStats.cpp and ../kernel/MoveStats.cpp are identical
tools_io $ g++ -c MoveStats.cpp -I ../common -o MoveStats.o -g -Wall -fopenmp
tools_io $ cd ../kernel
kernel $ g++ -c MoveStats.cpp -I ../common -o MoveStats.o -g -Wall -fopenmp
kernel $ cd ../tools_io
tools_io $ diff MoveStats.o ../kernel/MoveStats.o
Binary files MoveStats.o and ../kernel/MoveStats.o differ
tools_io $ ls -l MoveStats.o ../kernel/MoveStats.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 jody morpho 20632 Apr 13 11:22 ../kernel/MoveStats.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 jody morpho 20632 Apr 13 11:21 MoveStats.o
tools_io $ nm MoveStats.o > nmlocms.txt
tools_io $ nm ../kernel/MoveStats.o > nmkerms.txt
tools_io $ diff -s nmlocms.txt nmkerms.txt
Files nmlocms.txt and nmkerms.txt are identical
```

I use g++ 4.9.4 on gentoo:

```
tools_io $ g++ --version
g++ (Gentoo 4.9.4 p1.0, pie-0.6.4) 4.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What could cause the two object files to be different?

Can i trust them to be functionally equal?

Answer (score 1):

As you are compiling file with `-g` option, compiler add lots of debug information in section header.

If you drop `-g` option then you will get exact match.

Try to use `objdump` to visualize what is there inside object file.

And without `-g` if you have same code but just file name are different even then you will get difference, due to `SYMBOL TABLE` of object file also contain name of source file from which it was generated.

UPDATE: you can also try `readelf` even more information